# What is the difference between the Android OS and Android System?

Tags: battery

When I open my `Battery Usage`, there are two components enlisted as `Android OS` and `Android System`. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I got a rather meaningful suggestion on another forum that "Android OS" is actually the low-level kernel, while "Android System" is actually the higher-level OS service layer"

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10922010&postcount=3

Comment: This seems to make sense. Maybe it's right.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the difference is between them, however, if you're asking the question because 'Android OS' is using a large percentage of your battery life then you may have the '[Android OS drains battery](http://www.nexusoneforum.net/forum/nexus-one-tech-issues-bug-reports/11528-android-os-drains-battery-3.html#post95928)' bug.